# Transform all repeatable fileds into array - laravel backpack (fake fields)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-backpack, laravel-translatable

I'm using Laravel Backpack within Spatie Laravel Translatable.
I want to pass some translatable fields into the front but I've some issues.
I have a field named "extras" which is used by the backpack to store repeatable fields (I need this field to store some sections that I'll use later on the front-end later).
The problem is that all the content of these repeatable fields is not transformed into an array as excepted when I try `$page->toArray()`. They are still regular strings instead of arrays.

```
public function home() {
    $page = Page::findBySlug('accueil'); 

    if(!$page) {
        abort(404);
    }
    $locale = request()->getLocale(); 

    return Inertia::render('Home', [
        'title' => $page->getTranslation('title', $locale),
        'slug' => $page->getTranslation('slug', $locale),
        'content' => $page->getTrannslation('extras', $locale)
    ]);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide what kind of response you get and what kind of response you expect? It will help to answer this question. i guess.

Comment: $page->getTranslation('extras', $locale) return 
`array: [
"section-1-title" => "Hello world",
"section-1-blocs" => "[{"title": "Valeur", "content": "Bonjour"}]"
];`